# load python module out of a bash-script

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm currently trying to load "Crypto" out of a bash-script.

The snippet which i'll mention below is behind the installation of some packets and initializing some things.

```
su user1 -c 'python -c "import Crypto"'
```

i've tried some different combinations with " and ' + escaping but it wont work. If I put the exact line into the bash-console it works flawslessly.

I have to automate this because it will be used in an automatic-installation script.

Comment: it works for as a bash script too. Which bash are you using. Are you sure it is bash? echo $SHELL?  bash --version?

Comment: the console which i'm in when i'm directly connected to the server via ssh ist /bin/zsh ... but this should work if i'm running the script?

Comment: Have you checked `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH` variables have same values both during interactive session and script execution?

Comment: @p4r4n0id, if your script is BASH why do expect it work like your ZSH interactive console? Does your script contain /bin/sh or bin/bash on top? what is the default shell on the machine?

Comment: What exactly does "won't work" mean? Do you get an error message? What do you expect executing a Python 1-liner that imports a module and does nothing else to do?

Comment: i've added the line #!/bin/bash on top off the file yes. The bashscript isn't a oneliner.. later in the script im starting another *.sh script which uses this python module. The thing is that if i'm calling the module and the script inside the console it's working flawlessly but if i'm doint both in one script it doesn't.